# Is my Django middleware order is correct?

Tags: django, middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
'htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware',
'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',

'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',

'announce.middleware.AnnounceCookieMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'giaola.middleware.ForceDefaultLanguageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'mediagenerator.middleware.MediaMiddleware',
'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
'minidetector.Middleware',
# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'breadcrumbs.middleware.BreadcrumbsMiddleware',
'achievements.middleware.AutoAchievementChecker',
)
```

These are all my middleware and I'm not entirely sure they're in the correct order.

I have my doubts about GZip and HTMLmin being at the top with caching following after them but middleware has always been my weakpoint in Django.

"ForceDefaultLanguageMiddleware" is just to enforce the language, like so:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if request.META.has_key('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'):
        del request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

Any input would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I could tell you that.

Comment: Ha ha, sorry for being diqquish, my comment was intended to hint that your question title could replace 'Could you tell me if' with 'Is'. I know it sounds pernickity, but I suspect people on SO actually respond better to pointed, direct, short questions better then what might sound like less well edited, wooly, personal, opinion-based. Actually I'm not very qualified to help though, sorry. If you want to stimulate responses, you should probably explain why you think it's not in the right order, what you've tried, what happened, and what specific concerns you have.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for those suggestions. I'll try to enrich my question.